# converting a string to UTF8 with perl

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have some files which contains strings and need to convert them to UTF8 with perl is there any option with perl to run over those files and convert every string to utf8 and  if some strings are utf8 encoded to keep them as is ?

Answer (score 5):

You said some parts of the file are encoded using UTF-8 and some are encoded using something else, but you didn't specify the other encoding, and that's important.

Generally speaking, it's impossible to tell the encoding of a string by looking at it. But if you're dealing with a mix of US-ASCII, iso-8859-1, cp1252 and UTF-8, the odds are you can actually tell*, and someone has already written the tool for you.

[Encoding::FixLatin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encoding::FixLatin) comes with a script named `fix_latin` that will convert a file that's a mixture of the above encodings to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) module to convert between encodings. (No need to install anything; it's part of the core libraries.) Note that "*converting a string to UTF-8*" requires that you know what encoding you're converting from; there's no way to reliably identify 8-bit text encodings.